# How do I remove setInterval on a function?

Tags: javascript

I've a function called `fadeIn` and I want to return it until a condition is met.

I tried to put an alert in the else line along with `clearInterval(myVar)`, but it just keeps alerting.

CSS:

```
* {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#title {
    background-color: white;
    height: 50px;
}
audio {
    display: none;
}
#audio-icon {
    width: 50px;
    background-color: white;
}
#focus {
    background-color: black;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    border: 5px, solid, grey;
    border-style: inset;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#text-box {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    margin-top: 500px;
    float: left;
    border: 5px, solid, grey;
    border-style: inset;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#command-line {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    float: left;
    border: 5px, solid, grey;
    border-style: inset;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
#element {
    opacity: 0.1;
}
```

HTML:

```
<audio id="background-audio" controls autoplay="autoplay" loop>
    <source src="Darkness.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<div id="title">
    <img id="audio-icon" src="unmute.png" onclick="mute()">
    <img id="element" src="123.png">
</div>
<div id="focus">
    <div id="text-box">
        <div id="command-line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function fadeIn() {
    var myVar = setInterval(fadeIn, 500);
    var element = document.getElementById('element');


    if (element.style.opacity < 1) {
        element.style.opacity -= '-0.1';
    } else {
        clearInterval(myVar);

    }
}

function mute() {
    var audio = document.getElementById('background-audio');
    var img = document.getElementById('audio-icon');

    if (audio.muted) {
        audio.muted = false;
        img.src = 'unmute.png';
    } else {
        audio.muted = true;
        img.src = 'mute.png';
    }
}


document.onload = fadeIn();
```

UPDATE:

I have put the variables outside of the function and all of the sudden my code seems to work correctly. Not sure how this is possible since I have tried this already. My code wouldn't run at all and `alert` would keep alerting. Anyway thanks for all the help. This was my first question so apart from a few typos and the way I listed my code I don't really know why I get downvoted so any feedback about that is welcome! Here is my current working code:

```
<script>
            var myVar = setInterval(fadeIn, 500);
            var element = document.getElementById('element');

            function fadeIn() {
                console.log(element.style.opacity)
                if (element.style.opacity < 1) {
                element.style.opacity -= '-0.1';
                } else {
                clearInterval(myVar);
                }
            }

            function mute() {
            var audio = document.getElementById('background-audio');
            var img = document.getElementById('audio-icon');

            if (audio.muted) {
                audio.muted = false;
                img.src = 'unmute.png';
            } else {
                audio.muted = true;
                img.src = 'mute.png';
            }
        }


        document.onload = fadeIn();
        </script>
```

Comment: can you post html & css also?

Comment: Sorry about that. Just added html and css.

Comment: I put your code in a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hew5b39t/

Comment: Use clear timeout

Answer (score 0):

See the snippet .it will stop the reach with `1` .see the console.log

```js
   var myVar;
 var element = document.getElementById('element');

function fadeIn() {

              console.log(element.style.opacity)
                if (element.style.opacity < 1) {element.style.opacity -= -0.1;
                }
                else {
                    clearInterval(myVar);

                    }
            }

            function mute(){
                var audio = document.getElementById('background-audio');
                var img = document.getElementById('audio-icon');

                if (audio.muted) {
                    audio.muted = false;
                    img.src = 'unmute.png';
                }

                else {
                    audio.muted = true;
                    img.src = 'mute.png';
                }
            }


        window.onload =function(){
           myVar = setInterval(fadeIn, 500);
          }
```

```css
* {
                background-color: black;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                height: 100%;
            }

            #title {
                background-color: white;
                height: 50px;
            }

            audio {
                display: none;
            }

            #audio-icon {
                width: 50px;
                background-color: white;
            }

            #focus {
                background-color: black;
                margin: auto;
                width: 100%;
                height: 700px;
                border: 5px, solid, grey;
                border-style: inset;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }

            #text-box {
                background-color: black;
                width: 100%;
                height: 200px;
                margin-top: 500px;
                float: left;
                border: 5px, solid, grey;
                border-style: inset;
                border-radius: 10px;    
            }

            #command-line {
                background-color: black;
                width: 100%;
                height: 50px;
                margin-top: 150px;
                float: left;
                border: 5px, solid, grey;  
                border-style: inset;
                border-radius: 10px;
            }

            #element {
                opacity: 0.1;
            }
```

```html
<audio id="background-audio" controls autoplay="autoplay" loop>
        <source src="Darkness.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>


        <div id="title">
            <img id="audio-icon" src="unmute.png" onclick="mute()">
            <img id="element" src="123.png">
        </div>

        <div id="focus">
            <div id="text-box">
                <div id="command-line"></div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

```js
var myVar ;
var element = document.getElementById('element');
function fadeIn() {
                
               console.log(element.style.opacity)
                if (element.style.opacity < 1) {  
                  element.style.opacity -= -0.1;
                }
                else {
                    clearInterval(myVar);

                    }
            }
window.onload= function (){
  myVar = setInterval(fadeIn, 100);
  
  
  }
```

```html
<p id="element">hi</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `setInterval` is called independently of the if clauses, and that you're spamming unobserved intervals, intervals on which you don't have access anymore in the `fadeIn` function's block.

In this case you could have also used `setTimeout` instead, because it asynchronously evaluate its first argument just once, and because you don't have access to the intervals in the way you handle them.

Note: your condition for fade in is wrong, because you're decreasing the element opacity while its opacity is only bigger than `1`... i just changed this `1` by `0`.

```
var element, lastFadeInTimeout;
element = document.getElementById('element');

function fadeIn() {
    // The element is not totally
    // transparent yet
    if (element.style.opacity > 0) {
        element.style.opacity -= 0.1;
        // Let's wait 500ms to fade the element
        // again, only once
        lastFadeInTimeout = setTimeout(fadeIn, 500);
    }
}
```

Now, if you want to stop your fade-in action you can call `clearTimeout` with `lastFadeInTimeout`, where `lastFadeInTimeout` is the identifier of the last timeout created by the fade-in action.

```
clearTimeout(lastFadeInTimeout);
```

Answer (score -1):

You call the fadIn func onload (that's fine) but then you create a queue to execute the function every half a second, in each iteration you create another queue to execute the functio every half a sec.... sooner or later you're going to kill the browser with this.

What you're looking for is probably more like so:

```
function fadeIn() {
    if (opacity < 1) {
        opacity += 0.1;
        setTimeout(fadeIn, 500);
    }
}

document.onLoad = fadeIn();
```

If not for purpose of learning JavaScript you should probably do things like fadeIn / fadeOut using CSS transitions rather than JavaScript.